# Why doesn't vhdl recognize this port?

Tags: vhdl

I am new to VHDL and I'm trying to get this counter working with D flip flop components, but I keep getting the error "Error (10482): VHDL error at lab8.vhd(16): object "qn" is used but not declared" no matter what I try to do.

```html
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
ENTITY counter IS 
PORT(clk:IN STD_LOGIC;c0,c1:OUT STD_LOGIC);
END counter;

ARCHITECTURE func of counter IS

COMPONENT dFlipFlop IS
port(D,dflipclock:IN STD_LOGIC;q,qn:OUT STD_LOGIC);
END COMPONENT dFlipFlop;

BEGIN

G1:dFlipFlop
PORT MAP(D=>qn,dflipclock=>clk,q=>c0);

G2:dFlipFlop
PORT MAP(D=>qn,c0=>dflipclock,q=>c1);

END func;

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

ENTITY dFlipFlop IS
port(D,dflipclock:IN STD_LOGIC;q,qn:OUT STD_LOGIC);
END dFlipFlop;

ARCHITECTURE flipper OF dFlipFlop IS
SIGNAL currentState:STD_LOGIC:='0';--not sure what STD_LOGIC initial value is so im setting it to zero here
BEGIN
PROCESS(dflipclock)
BEGIN
IF(dflipclock'EVENT AND dflipclock ='1') THEN --positive edge triggered
currentState<=D;
END IF;
END PROCESS;
q<=currentState;
qn<=not currentState;
END flipper;
```

I feel like I'm making some kind of stupid newbie error but I've been staring at this thing for hours now and I can't for the life of me figure out what wrong.

Comment: `qn` missing from port map statement. If you want to leave it open, `qn => open` will do that. If you want to feed it back to D, declare a local signal `signal feedback : std_logic;` and map both ports to it `PORT MAP(D=>feedback, dflipclock=>clk, q=>c0, qn => feedback);`

Comment: Thank you! The feedback solution worked

Comment: A component declaration is a separate declarative region and the port names used as formals aren't visible in the enclosing region. Those ports are made visible on the left hand side of an association in a port map because of an implicit component configuration. qn can't be used as an actual for G1 or G2, nor can dflipclock for G2.